# Examples of physiological differences between isolated & non-isolated individuals

Tags: sociality, polymorphism

I'm looking for examples of organisms (or biological units at some other scale, like cells) whose physical and/or behavioral properties develop differently depending on whether the individual is in close contact with others. In particular, I'm interested in cases where individuals are specialized for fairly narrow functions as part of their usual collective existence (e.g. as animals in a society or cells in a tissue) but develop facilities for more autonomous/self-sufficient operation (possibly including significant anatomical changes) when isolated.

The example that originally came to mind (which isn't really even what I'm looking for) is heart cells that beat together when touching. A slightly better one might be colonial organisms like [pyrosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrosome). I hope there are even better examples in which the "solitary" form exhibits distinct differences from the "grouped" one. Are there animals or plants that do this? Microscopic organisms (maybe other zooids)? Thanks in advance.

(Sorry if this question is too vague/abstract. For more context: I'm helping a friend with some nonfiction writing, and we're looking for a metaphor from nature to introduce a passage about how pandemic-related isolation has spurred some people to "blossom" artistically/intellectually/etc.; it'd be really cool if there were an organism that similarly "grows into a new version of itself" when separated from its neighbors.)

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain your goal; otherwise it's a pretty broad question that could possibly be answered any number of ways, which isn't a good format for a SE question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Edited to explain my goal.

Comment: Just for info, we have a [worldbuilding.se] site as well as a [writing.se] site -  this question might have easily fit on the former, more-or-less as is.

Comment: Thanks! A fictional example of what I'm describing wouldn't be as compelling as a real one from biology, so I'll leave my question here unless it's deemed not appropriate.

Comment: You can ask for a "finite list" of real-life examples, but you'd need to specify environment and such. Worldbuilding uses real science to create fictional worlds (and, to be fair, there's quite a few magic related ones too). Not an answer to this, as it's late for me to start writing answers, but what leapt to mind immediately on reading it was [slime molds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold), worth a read.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] or delete your question accordingly. I have voted to close this as needing focus — this is a question that would require a textbook to answer, which is both impractical and expressly off-topic for this site. In addition, as currently written the cells in any multicellular organism would seem to fit your criteria, as would any social organism. Plants also grow differently when crowded vs. isolated — e.g. compare tree farms to isolated trees ...